# Limitation of HTMLUnit driver for headless testing

Tags: selenium, htmlunit-driver

Can I perform following functions using HTML Unit Driver headless browser automation?

1. Is it possible to take snapshot?
2. Can click any hyperlink ?
3. Possible to handle pop-ups?

Please help

I am planning to do automation using HTMLUnit driver

Comment: Yes, All the mentioned points are possible through `HTMLUnit driver`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You can perform all operations as per of your all 3 point using headless browser. Don't use `HTMLUnit` as it have many configuration issue.

PhamtomJS was another approach for headless browser but PhantomJs is having bug these days because of poorly maintenance of it.

You can use chromedriver itself for headless jobs.

You just need to pass one option in chromedriver as below:-

```
chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
```

Full code will appear like this :-

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\Workspace\\JmeterWebdriverProject\\src\\lib\\chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--start-maximized");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Till now I was aware of only two ways " HTMLUnit n phantoms". Bus now I can do it using Chrome drive r as well mentioned above

Comment: I will give try to Chrome drive option

Comment: Yes you can perform all web driver operations using headless.. operation like switching to popup, screenshot everything you can do

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I will implement the same and will accept your answer

Comment: Which Chrome driver needed to do headless testing .. 
It can be done on windows ..rt .. ?????

Comment: Can I run script on Windows... I am planning on windows only for now .. is it possible ???

Comment: Yes you can .. no issue

Comment: Does it work when we had window based popup? I used autoIT script to accept the window based script. is it work in headless mode of chrome browser?

Comment: I don't think autoIT works in headless mode so you can use java script or Actions to handle your pop-up instead of autoIT